# Display local HTML page from custom control

Tags: c#, controls

I want to make a control, that acts as a wrapper for a Javascript library. It's a web browser control that displays an HTML page that I have written, wrapping the JS functions with C# ones.

My problem is how to bundle the .html page with the control's build.

I want to include the html file as a relative path. What I'm doing is:

```
this.Url = new Uri(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"WebPage\leaflethtml.html"));
```

inside the control's constructor.

The problem that arises, is that in the designer, the relative path changes, to that of the current working directory (the directory of Visual Studio's designer), so the Uri looks at `<VisualStudioFilePath>\WebPage\leaflethtml.html` instead of `<ControlBinary>\WebPage\leaflethtml.html` and returns an error message (it's not something major, but it's not very elegant).

Is there some better way?

PS I've tried

```
if (!this.DesignMode)
{
    this.Url = new Uri(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"WebPage\leaflethtml.html"));
}
```

but it still gets executed in the designer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the html and JavaScript files as embedded resources.  This can be done by changing the Build Action in the File Properties dialog in Visual Studio.

[image]

The files can then be loaded using Reflection, for example:

```
var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("namespace.filename.extension");
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't even know about build actions!